# Failure in Identification of blackberry sign code registration key

Tags: blackberry, sign

The problem we are facing is that...  while registering the signature key it is asking for the registration key and private pin...  i have created the private key in step 4 but i don't have any clue of what the registration key is or...how it looks like...  .
I have - New JDE Keys Order and tried it but it failed.
so please help me in identifying the registration key ....  it would be really great if u can show me samples of how a registration key will look like..

Answer (score 0):

Registration key is a 10 digits registration pin that you have entered in the order form and private key password that you have created in step 4.

for full instruction read this article
[Blackberry application signing](http://blog.vimviv.com/blackberry/blackberry-application-code-signing/)

Comment: thanks vivart. i registered the .csi files. where i put the three .csi values. I am eclipse plugin for developing blackberry application. when i go to the Blackberry->Install Signatures nothing happened.

Comment: click on your application.cod file, you will get a popup window-> here click on the request button. after that it will ask for password->enter password and click on ok.